# Cannot assign by reference to overloaded object

Tags: php, wordpress, object, overloading

this is a part of my wordpress theme and it gives me an error for the last line of code.
Iam running wordpress 3.5.1 on PHP 5.4

```
Fatal error: Cannot assign by reference to overloaded object in C:\server\htdocs\web\digitalnak\wp-content\themes\rework\framework\php\PeTheme\PeThemeGallery.php on line 234
```

and here is the code

```
 $post =& get_post($id);
    if (!$post ) return $post;
    $null = null;
    if ($post->post_type != "gallery") return $null;

    $meta =& $this->master->meta->get($id,$post->post_type);
    $post->meta =& $meta;
```

Comment: Which of those is line 234? What version of PHP are you running? What is the theme you're running? What version of Wordpress?

Comment: 234 is the $post->meta =& $meta , i have php version 5.4 and wordpress 3.5.1

Comment: What kind of object is `$post`?

Answer (score 0):

Without having looked at anything – and as such this may not work at all – try this:

```
$post =& get_post($id);
if (!$post ) return $post;

$null = null;
if ($post->post_type != "gallery") return $null;

$meta =& $this->master->meta->get($id,$post->post_type);
$post->meta = $meta;
```

Looks like you're assigning a value by reference to an ArrayAccess object. This doesn't work in some versions of PHP. I can't judge this, but it looks as if this code is using pass-by-reference very heavily, possibly more than necessary.